# Has the strength of the historical-archaeological method ever been tested experimentally?

Tags: historiography, science, archaeology, methodology

Historians routinely draw quite far-reaching conclusions about all aspects of society from archaeological artifacts and textual documents that – naturally – represent only a minuscule fraction of all the artifacts and documents that existed in the time and place that is being investigated.

I have always held doubts about the validity of the boldest of those conclusions and have devised a simple experiment that I believe would shed some light on the strength of the standard methods of the historical-archaeological sciences:

1. Take a *modern* society that the historians participating in the experiment (say, United States-based historians specializing in classical European antiquity) are not familiar with (e.g. rural Japan)
2. Randomly sample artifacts and documents from that society, emphasizing such artifacts and documents that are capable of surviving several centuries
3. Provide those samples to the historians without any context whatsoever (except for the location of the "find")
4. Compare the conclusions drawn by the historians with reality

**Has an experiment of this type ever been conducted?**

Comment: The academic discipline you're looking for is "experimental archaeology" - it's a pretty active field. In addition to applying their techniques to modern societies, they recreate artifacts using period technology and test their usage in real-world conditions.

Comment: what he describes is **not** what experimental archaeology does.  EA is trying to recreate artifacts that we don't find in the dirt.  The poster wants to test the acuteness of the conclusions found by archeology with a 'test' set of finds that we know the results about.  The problem is that you won't get true archaeologists to start a new career digging up fake artifacts to start a new field to compare with the actual results. Humans aren't lab rats for your amusement.

Comment: This would test the historians' ability to draw valid conclusions from archaeological data. I strongly suspect that the results of such experiment would be discouraging. Therefore I doubt that historians would knowingly subject their reputation to such a test. It would be a magnificent experiment though.

Comment: I think it is paranoid to suggest that not only this generation but all generations' archaeologists are fakes and liars trying to save their reputations rather than people trying to discover the truth the best they can.

Comment: If it is true that historians would refuse such a test based on the fear that it might lead to unpleasant conclusions then indeed I have to conclude that archaeology is one big fake. Imagine a physicist, having published a new theory, refusing to verify that theory against known results, citing "I'm not a lab rat" or similar nonsense. He'd be dismissed as a crank in the blink of an eye, and rightfully so.  I sincerely hope that you are wrong and such ridiculous arrogance is not actually found among today's archaeologists.

Comment: `Historians routinely draw quite far-reaching conclusions ` Would you mind to give us an example of far-reaching conlusion in archaeological research? Regarding experiment, how can we measure success and failure in such an experiment?

Comment: @defaultlocale: Here is an example of an article that I (admittedly not being an expert in the field) feel draws an almost ridiculously far-fetched conclusion from very little data: http://web.archive.org/web/20070608101037/http://www.pubs.asce.org/ceonline/0699feat.html. The article uses the **critical path method**, a technique from _modern_ project management, to arrive at the conclusion that the construction of the Great Pyramid of Giza (whose exact purpose and method of construction are still a mystery) took 131,200 man-years to complete.

Comment: @pew I'm not sure I follow. As far as I can tell (I just skimmed an article) authors claim that it is *possible* to build the Great Pyramid of Giza in 10 years with 13200 men using modern project management and ancient technologies. Sorry, I couldn't find any far-reaching conclusions on how pyramid was actually built by ancient Egyptians.

Comment: The purpose of the Great Pyramid is well known.  It is to be a huge impressive pile of rock.

Comment: @defaultlocale: The subtitle of the article clearly states "[...] provides some surprising answers to the question of how the Great Pyramid at Giza **was built.**"

Comment: @pew Subtitles are deceiving, especially in online articles :). But it's reasoning that matters. To quote from article: `While there is uncertainty as to precisely how the Egyptians built the Great Pyramid, there is certainty about the fact that it was done.`

Comment: @Oldcat: Fakes and liars is too harsh, I'm sure -- but could it nonetheless be possible that our historical methods may be less accurate than we think? I am not sure what would be so bad about trying such an experiment. You don't need to make it anything super-complicated to the point they need to make a "career" out of the experiment -- just a simple test case or two. Why wouldn't perhaps historians themselves be interested in running such a test, given that as any good field of scholarship wanting to improve the accuracy of one's methods should be a top concern?

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of, but I'd think that such a process would be so far removed from quantifiable science that it'd be rendered pointless.

The job of a historian is to make best guesses given the evidence that's presented itself. Given that it's easy for two different historians to look at the same evidence and draw different conclusions. Then without really *knowing* the reality of the situation you can't quantify accuracy of the historian's predictions.

Instead we could go about the process you described but that wouldn't represent an accurate model of different civilizations and circumstances. In the life sciences we do testing on animals that represent a model that's close enough for practical purposes, but there are way too may variables to do the same with history.

With all of that in mind it's not so much important to gauge how correct historians are, but rather that when historians make predictions to make the reader aware of the small amount of evidence involved and how likely what they are saying is to be true.

Comment: Agreed; for science as well as history (and hell, most fields), the reporting of it (whether by the researchers or journalists of the field) often presumes the reader knows just how precarious the findings may or may not be... and the confidence of many researchers is astounding to a degree worthy of psychological study.